# Where it was said "There is no fire in jahannam"?

Tags: source-identification

I remember hearing a story. If I recall it correctly, one sahaba sees other one in dream. And in dream other sahaba says something like "there is no fire in jahannam, everyone brings it's fire from [dunya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunya)". Can anyone identify this story exactly? If so, is it an authentic one?

Comment: wouldn't that contradict the hadith that says the fire in hell is 10 times hotter than on earth, and the one that says when its hot on earth its because the hellfire just got hotter? we can infer from these hadiths that there is hell there currently and hellfire is nothing like earths fire

Comment: @NesreenA It looks like it would. But I remember hearing this from somewhere, can't remember the details.

Comment: I do not remember this story. but I think it says hell itself does not have fire and fire is from human. hadith says fire is produced from human himself and fire is evil deeds taken to hell from world (Dunya)

Answer (score 2):

Do these help?

> … save yourselves and your families from a Fire whose fuel is Men and
>   Stones [the fake gods you used to believed beside Allah?] …
>   (At-Tahrim:6)

and

> … then fear the Fire whose fuel is men and stones,- which is prepared
>   for those who reject Faith … (Al-Baghareh:24)

Focusing on the word "**fuel**" in these verses, it may implies that "no fuel no fire", so that "if there are no unbeliever in God and fake gods then there would be no fire either"!

Comment: @ashes999 It does :) What owari means is that probably "There IS fire in jahannam”.

Comment: @ashes999, actually I focus on the word "fuel" in these verses, no fuel no fire, so that no unbeliever in God and fake gods there would be no fire as well! However, the cited verses may on the other hand only imply that some human bring the fire for all of those in hell, maybe yes maybe not, more research is required for that ti be answered, although as anyone carry only his deeds that would be less probable I guess.